# sscanf multiple format specifiers to single array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, scanf

Is it possible to run `sscanf` with multiple format specifiers which will each set a single item in an array? Currently, I have to specify the pointers to each array slot separately, which feels very repetitive:

```
unsigned int buffer[8];
sscanf(
        line,
        "%6o %6o %6o %6o %6o %6o %6o %6o",
        buffer + 0,
        buffer + 1,
        buffer + 2,
        buffer + 3,
        buffer + 4,
        buffer + 5,
        buffer + 6,
        buffer + 7);
```

I'm looking for something similar to JavaScript's [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) or Python's [`*`-operator for unpacking argument lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
sscanf(
        line,
        "%6o %6o %6o %6o %6o %6o %6o %6o",
        ...buffer);
```

At the moment, this fails with the following error:

> file.c:42:21: error: format ‘%o’ expects a matching ‘unsigned int *’ argument [-Werror=format=]

Which is kind of expected. How can I tell `sscanf` to put each format specifier value into consecutive slots in the array? Is it possible? If not, is there a clever workaround (hack)?

Comment: "How can I tell sscanf to put each format specifier value into consecutive slots in the array? Is it possible?" No it's not possible.

Comment: knittl, What should happen when the text input is _negative_ like `"-1 -2 -3 ..."`.  Is that acceptable or error?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica the file/string will never contain negative numbers. If it does, I cannot process it. Thus erroring out would be OK.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I tell `sscanf` to put each format specifier value into consecutive slots in the array? Is it possible?

According to [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) there is no such conversion specifier.

> If not, is there a clever workaround (hack)?

Yes, loop and extract one at a time. [`strtoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) may be useful in this case.

Example:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t scan_uint_array(const char *line, unsigned int buffer[], size_t count, int base)
{
    char *str_end;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        unsigned long tmp = strtoul(line, &str_end, base);
        if(str_end == line) return i; // no conversion done
        if(errno == ERANGE) return i; // out of range for ULONG
        if(tmp > UINT_MAX) {          // out of range for UINT
            errno = ERANGE;
            return i;
        }
        buffer[i] = tmp; // all good, save this
        line = str_end;  // move line to where the next scan should be done
    }
    return count;
}

#define Size(x) (sizeof (x) / sizeof *(x))

int main() {
    unsigned int buffer[8];
    size_t ex = scan_uint_array(" 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ", buffer, Size(buffer), 8);
    
    printf("extracted=%zu wanted=%zu\n", ex, Size(buffer));
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < ex; ++i)
        printf("%u ", buffer[i]);
}
```

Output

```
extracted=7 wanted=8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: As always, C forces you to spend hours to re-invent what other languages provide to you for free, ending up with a slower, less general solution that is typically buggy in its first iteration and adds boilerplate code that nobody is actually interested in. It is always very sobering for me to return to C or even C++ from C#. Productivity seems to slow to a crawl.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Ah, but its basic-ness and adaptability often results in using C as one of the first targets for a new machine, thus allowing rapid use of decades of existing code.  We could debate the pros and cons of C, but this is not the place for that.  Suffice it to say the languages all has their +/-.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica For sure. I just couldn't resist to make that observation.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I tell sscanf to put each format specifier value into consecutive slots in the array? Is it possible? If not, is there a clever workaround (hack)?

Use a loop.

Robust code also detects if `line` does not contain 8 sets of octal numeric text.

---

An alternative to [`strtol()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70555138/2410359) loop is `sscanf()` with `"%6o %n"`.

`" %n"` scans optional white-space and then saves the offset of the scan.

```
size_t n = sizeof buffer / sizeof buffer[0];  // 8

const char *p = line;
size_t i;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  int n = 0;
  if (sscanf(p, "%6o %n", &buffer[i], &n) != 1) {  // or use strtol()
    Handle_scanf_failure(); // Add user code here to cope with this error
  }
  p += n; // Advance p to the next part of the buffer
}
if (*p != '\0') {
  Handle_junk_at_end_of_buffer(); // Add user code here to cope with this error
}
```

`strtol()` handles overflow better than `"%o"`, but since we have a max *width* of 6 octal digits, that would prevent overflow with 32-bit `unsigned`.